# node.js jenkins npm install fails

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm

I've been following the instructions here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/setting-up-continuous-integration-continuous-deployment-with-jenkins--cms-21511

When I create the production droplet all goes well.  The new node.js works great and the npm install works.

When, however, I create the jenkins droplet, jenkins comes up fine, but the auto-install of the git package stops when it tries to find bower.

My package.json says:

```
{
  "name": "mean",
  "description": "Full-Stack JavaScript with MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, and Node.js",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x",
    "npm": "1.4.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "grunt",
    "test": "grunt test",
    "postinstall": "bower install --config.interactive=false"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.10.1",
    "express-session": "~1.9.1",
    "body-parser": "~1.9.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.2",
    "compression": "~1.2.0",
    "method-override": "~2.3.0",
    "morgan": "~1.4.1",
    "connect-mongo": "~0.4.1",
    "connect-flash": "~0.1.1",
    "helmet": "~0.5.0",
    "consolidate": "~0.10.0",
    "swig": "~1.4.1",
    "mongoose": "~3.8.8",
    "passport": "~0.2.0",
    "passport-local": "~1.0.0",
    "passport-facebook": "~1.0.2",
    "passport-twitter": "~1.0.2",
    "passport-linkedin": "~0.1.3",
    "passport-google-oauth": "~0.1.5",
    "passport-github": "~0.1.5",
    "lodash": "~2.4.1",
    "forever": "~0.11.0",
    "bower": "~1.3.8",
    "grunt-cli": "~0.1.13",
    "glob": "~4.0.5",
    "async": "~0.9.0",
    "nodemailer": "~1.3.0",
    "chalk": "~0.5",
    "ejs": "~1.0.0",
    "jquery": "~2.1.0",
    "multer": "~0.1.7",
    "busboy": "~0.2.9",
    "connect-busboy":"~0.0.2",
    "fs-extra":"~0.16.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt-concurrent": "~1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-csslint": "^0.3.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-env": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.9.0",
    "grunt-mocha-test": "~0.12.1",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-node-inspector": "~0.1.3",
    "grunt-nodemon": "~0.3.0",
    "karma": "~0.12.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.2",
    "karma-coverage": "~0.2.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.2.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.2",
    "karma-requirejs": "^0.2.2",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~1.0.0",
    "requirejs": "^2.1.15",
    "should": "~4.1.0",
    "supertest": "~0.14.0"
  }
}
```

And I get the error in the jenkins console log:

```
+ npm install
npm WARN package.json mean@0.0.1 No repository field.

> mean@0.0.1 postinstall /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Paygevity/workspace
> bower install --config.interactive=false

sh: 1: bower: not found

npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-43-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! mean@0.0.1 postinstall: `bower install --config.interactive=false`
npm ERR! Exit status 127
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the mean@0.0.1 postinstall script 'bower install --config.interactive=false'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the mean package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     bower install --config.interactive=false
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls mean
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: bower needs to be in the path.  This is often done with a global install such as `npm install bower -g`.  Assuming you have access to the command line and rights to do a global install, that should fix the issue.

Comment: Dammit!  I cannot tell you how many times (I think) I ran that command sudo npm -g install bower and it did not fix the prob.  I run it one more time to humor you and it works.  Thanks Matt!

Comment: You don't have to install bower in global. You can use `./node_modules/.bin/bower` or just `bower` as it should have been added to your path by npm.